# Custom LinearLayout to contain predifined views

Tags: android

I want to create custom LinearLayout which will contain some hardcoded views. How can I do that?
Code you asked:

```
MyElement extends LinearLayout{

    @Override
    void on...(args){
        super(args)
        setChilds();
    }

    void setChilds() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Google is the source of all knowledge. Did you tried something? if yes post it please

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom layout using below code :

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View subView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, null);

LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(Context);
 ll.addView(subView);

And if you post some line of code then I will help you more easily.